# How to get data attribute of the element that contains a specific class?

Tags: javascript, parallax

I'm making a parallax effect in Vanilla JavaScript ES5.

What I want to achieve is to set a data attribute, and put in the speed that I want the parallax to have.

Here's the codepen: https://codepen.io/Aurelian/pen/vdQMYo?editors=0011

Here is the HTML:

```
<section class="page-intro">
    <div class="page-intro__img js-parallax" data-parallax-speed="-0.5" style="background-image: url(https://metrouk2.files.wordpress.com/2017/03/512366437.jpg?w=748&h=498&crop=1);">

    </div>
    <div class="page-intro__overlay"></div>

    <!-- Two Different Parts, big and small -->
    <div class="page-intro__content">
        <h1 class="page-intro__title">Puppy</h1>
        <span class="page-intro__sub-title">Explore how my design process can help your business grow and succeed.</span>
    </div>

    <div class="page-intro__content">

    </div>

</section>
<section class="page-intro">
    <div class="page-intro__img js-parallax" data-parallax-speed="-0.2" style="background-image: url(https://metrouk2.files.wordpress.com/2017/03/512366437.jpg?w=748&h=498&crop=1);">

    </div>
    <div class="page-intro__overlay"></div>

    <!-- Two Different Parts, big and small -->
    <div class="page-intro__content">
        <h1 class="page-intro__title">Puppy</h1>
        <span class="page-intro__sub-title">Explore how my design process can help your business grow and succeed.</span>
    </div>

    <div class="page-intro__content">

    </div>

</section>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Here is the JS:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var parallax = document.getElementsByClassName('js-parallax');
  var xScrollPosition;
  var yScrollPosition;

  console.log("Data speed is:" + dataSpeed);

    function setTranslate(xPos, yPos, el) {
        el.style.transform = "translate3d(" + xPos + ", " + yPos + "px, 0)";
    }

  function scrollLoop() {
      xScrollPosition = window.scrollX;
      yScrollPosition = window.scrollY;

      for(var i = 0; i < parallax.length; i++) {
        parallaxEl = parallax[i];
        var dataSpeed = parallaxEl.getAttribute('data-parallax-speed');
        setTranslate(0, yScrollPosition * dataSpeed, parallaxEl);

      }
  }
    window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollLoop, false);
```

}

Comment: You question is confused. You want to set an attribute per your question, but your code (in `setTranslate()`) sets a style property. so which do you want to achieve?

Comment: If you look at codepen example, you can see it doesn't work because it has no value.

Comment: I need to pass in the Value to be there, but the value needs to come form the data attribute, and it needs to be the exact attribute where the js-parallax is. So I have say 10pictures, and I can set them diferent speed through data attribute.

Comment: So this is incorrect: _What I want to achieve is to set a data attribute_ and you should revise your question to indicate that what you want. to achieve is to retrieve a data attribute value and use that value to change some CSS on the parallax element.

Comment: Well, I didn't put a full stop there, but a comma "What I want to achieve is to set a data attribute, and put in the speed that I want the parallax to have." , and reading the code : var dataSpeed = parallaxEl.getAttribute('data-parallax-speed');
        setTranslate(0, yScrollPosition * dataSpeed, parallaxEl); 

So thta's what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with `.getAttribute()` used with `data-` attributes. The proper way to access those is through the HTMLElement's `dataset` map. Docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

This works: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zRMgyX?editors=0011

```
window.onload = function() {
  var parallax = document.querySelectorAll('.js-parallax');
  var xScrollPosition;
  var yScrollPosition;

//  console.log("Data speed is:" + dataSpeed);

    function setTranslate(xPos, yPos, el) {
        el.style.transform = "translate3d(" + xPos + ", " + yPos + "px, 0)";
    }

  function scrollLoop() {
      xScrollPosition = window.scrollX;
      yScrollPosition = window.scrollY;
      parallax.forEach(p=>{
         var dataSpeed = p.dataset.parallaxSpeed; 
         setTranslate(0, yScrollPosition * dataSpeed, p);
      })
  }
    window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollLoop, false);

}
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried it but can't seem to make it work though, it doesn't seem it get's the value - https://codepen.io/Aurelian/pen/vdQMYo?editors=0011

Comment: I just added a link to a codepen in the answer - can you check that one? note I changed the `getElementsByClassName()` to `querySelectorAll()` so I could use `forEach`. Sorry if I changed too much.

Comment: Awesome. Glad to help.